# Terminated due to timeout? How to improve DFS

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph-theory, depth-first-search

I tried a hackerrank problem [link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/journey-to-the-moon) and that gives me terminated due to time out for 3 test case. There I used a dfs method to check for the connected components and get the ans using sum of products of each disjoint elements.(a*b + a*c + a*d + b*c + b*d + c*d == a*b + (a+b)*c + (a+b+c)*d). I need to know what's wrong with my dfs ;{( and how can I improve this. I need not to have a solution to the hackerrank problem. Just need to know what are my mistakes.

Here's my code. Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

#define For(i,a,n) for (int i=a; i<n; i++)
typedef vector<int> vi;

// returns no. of connected nodes to a given node
int connected(int node, vector<vi> adj, bool visited[]){
    int count = 0;
    for(auto x: adj[node]){
        if(visited[x]) continue;
        visited[x] = true;
        count += connected(x, adj, visited) + 1;
    }
    return count;
}

void dfs(int nodes, vector<vi> adj, bool visited[]){
    int ans = 0;
    visited[nodes] = true;
    int current_sum = connected(nodes, adj, visited) + 1;

    while(nodes--){
        if(visited[nodes]) continue;
        visited[nodes] = true;
        int out = connected(nodes, adj, visited) + 1;
        ans += current_sum*out;
        current_sum += out;    
    }
    cout<< ans;
}

int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0), cin.tie(0), cout.tie(0);

    int a,b,edges,nodes;
    cin>>nodes>>edges;
    bool visited[nodes];
    fill(visited, visited + nodes, 0);
    vector<vi> adj(nodes);

    // adj[i] gives the directly connected nodes to i
    while(edges--){
        cin>>a>>b;
        adj[a].push_back(b);
        adj[b].push_back(a);
    }

    dfs(nodes-1, adj, visited);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post to CodeReiew SE.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Isn't that only for working code?

Comment: @BessieTheCow OP's title suggests that the code works but it's too slow and is asking for improvement.

Comment: Agreed. Looks like a candidate for Code Review, but before you try that see what happens if you pass the `vector` by reference rather than by value to reduce the amount of unnecessary copying.

Comment: @user4581301  thanks that really helped and reduced it to one test of failure.

Comment: @Marco Bonelli  .....sorry. I am new here. how to post to code review

Comment: @rusiruthushara CodeReview is another website similar to Stack Overflow, you can visit it [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). If your code is working and needs improvement, I would suggest you to delete the question from here and ask it there, since CodeReview is better suited for this kind of question.

Comment: @Marco Bonelli thanks a lot I'll try that.

Comment: Code that is too slow isn't *working code*, it will be closed as off-topic on CR.